# Objective C - how to append a number to the end of another number?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm wanting to append a number to the end of another number, example:

123 + 4

1234

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
NSInteger a = 123;
NSInteger b = 4;
NSInteger c = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%ld", (long)a, (long)b] integerValue];
```

Comment: I'd say this solution is working fine, but is probably consuming a bit more resources, than the one with basic operations.

Comment: NSIntegers us %ld not %d, ints use %d. Also you assign a NSInteger to an intValue, it loses precision if you do this.

Comment: NSInteger should be casted to int. In newest Xcode there is a warning.

Comment: You should cast an `NSInteger` used with `%ld` to `long`, not to `int`. An `int` is always 32 bits, and casting to it could truncate an `NSInteger`'s value under 64 bit, since `NSInteger` is `typedef`'ed as a `long`.

Answer (score 13):

Get the length of the second number, `k`.  Multiply first number by 10<sup>k</sup>.  Add in second number.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why "k"?

Comment: "k" is the length of the number you're appending to the first. It determines how many extra zeroes you need at the end of the first number, so that you can then just add the second number to the shifted first number.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it all numerically then @bdares is the right direction, here is one option for the missing detail (typed at terminal):

```
NSInteger a = 123;
NSInteger b = 4;

NSInteger ab = a * (NSInteger)pow(10.0, ceil(log10(b+1))) + b;
```

`pow`, `ceil` & `log10` are from `math.h`